# tableHeaderView' height is changed automatically after pushing a new viewcontrolller and come back

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

A header View is set to a `tableView` and the header View is an xib file using auto layout. When clicking a tableView cell and push another `tableViewController` ,then click back button to pop the tableViewController .However the headerView's height is changed from 98 to 34 and there is a gap between the headerView and the first cell.This is really odd.Is there anybody know how to solve this problem?Thank you very much!
[pic with the right headerview height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfsuG.png)

[pic with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E28s.png)

Comment: Can you show screenshot of your problem

Comment: Show me your heightForRowAtIndexPath method .. ?

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala Hi,I have uploaded two pic links ,pls check .thank you !

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan Hi -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [_messageTableViewCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height+1;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your viewWill appear like this

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: wow!!!!!Thank you so much !It did works.I use the second line.Thank you again .This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: try this] or add in programming to disable the insets

```
   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

or if you are using navigation controller

`self.navigationController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: Thank you !I have tried this ,but it does't work  and I have uploaded two screenshots .

Comment: I had also faced similar problem for tableview. But i have solved by untick this bool.